# File Management for Large Quantity of Files

Tags: sql-server, xml, windows, relational-database

Before I begin, I would like to express my appreciation for all of the insight I've gained on stackoverflow and everyone who contributes. I have a general question about managing large numbers of files. I'm trying to determine my options, if any. Here it goes.

Currently, I have a large number of files and I'm on Windows 7. What I've been doing is categorizing the files by copying them into folders based on what needs to be processed together. So, I have one set that contains the files by date (for long term storage) and another that contains the copies by category (for processing and calculations). Of course this doubles my data each time. Now I'm having to create more than one set of categories; 3 copies to be exact. This is quadrupling my data.

For the processing side of things, the data ends up in excel. Originally, all the data was brough into excel. Then all organization and filtering was performed in excel. This was time consuming and not easily maintainable over the long term. Later the work load was shifted to the file system itself, which lightened the work in excel.

The long and short of it is that this is an extremely inefficient use of disk space. What would be a better way of handling this?

Things that have come to mind:

1. Overlapping Folders

   - Is there a way to create a folder that only holds the addresses of a file, rather than copying the file. This way I could have two folders reference the same file.
   - To my understanding, a folder is a file listing the memory addresses of the files inside of it, but on Windows a file can only be contained in one folder.
2. Microsoft SQL Server

   - Not sure what could be done here.
3. Symbolic Links

   - I'm not an administrator, so I cannot execute the mklink command.
   - Also, I'm uncertain about any performance issues with this.
4. A Junction

   - Apparently not allowed for individual files, only folders in windows.
5. Search folders (*.search-ms)

   - Maybe I'm missing something, but to my knowledge there is no way to specify individual files to be listed.
6. Hashing the files

   - Creating hash tags for all the files, would allow for the files to be stored once. But then I have no idea how I would handle the hash tags.
7. XML

   - Maybe I could use xml files to attach meta data to the files and somehow search using them.
8. Database File System

   - I recently came across this concept in my search. Not sure how it would apply Windows.

Comment: What type of information is being stored in the Excel files?

Comment: Can you tell us the content of the file and why duplication is needed? If information is confidential, just use an equivalent generic example. It will help us thinking about SharePoint, database or other software to meet your needs

Answer (score 0):

I have found a partial solution. First, I discovered that the laptop I'm using is actually logged in as Administrator. As an alternative to options 3 and 4, I have decided to use hard-links, which are part of the NTFS file system. However, due to the large number of files, this is unmanageable using the following command from an elevated command prompt:

```
mklink /h <source\file> <target\file>
```

Luckily, Hermann Schinagl has created the [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html) application for Windows Explorer and a very insightful reading of how Junctions, Symbolic Links, and Hard Links work. The only reason that this is currently a partial solution, is due to a separate problem with Windows Explorer, which I intend to post as a separate question. Thank you Hermann.